# Cross validation in Django Admin between Parent and Child inline models

Tags: django

I have a Post model, which can contain either images or links to videos, or both.
The requirement is that every Post must have at least one image or one link to video. 
My current problem is I don't know where to place the correct validation to make.

I tried to override the functions add_view and change_view in PostAdmin but could not make it work.
I also tried to make some validations in ImagenPostAdminFormSet and VideoLinkPostAdminFormSet, but were useless as either of them can be empty, but not both.

Following is my code for the models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ....
    nombre_post = models.CharField('Nombre del Posteo', max_length=255)
    descripcion = models.CharField('Descripción', max_length=255)
    ....

class ImagenPost(models.Model): 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="imagen_post")
    imagen_post = ContentTypeRestrictedFileField('Imagen del Posteo',      upload_to=media_posteos, help_text='Formatos válidos: jpg, jpeg, gif, png')
     ...

class VideoLinkPost(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="video_link_post")
    video_link = EmbedVideoField('Link de Video', max_length=150, help_text='Ingresar Link de Video')
    ...
```

Following the code for Admin:

```
class ImagenPostAdminInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ImagenPost
    form  = ImagenPostAdminForm
    formset = ImagenPostAdminFormSet
    extra = 1

class VideoLinkPostAdminInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = VideoLinkPost
    form  = VideoLinkPostAdminForm
    formset = VideoLinkPostAdminFormSet
    extra = 1

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostAdminForm
    inlines = [ImagenPostAdminInline, VideoLinkPostAdminInline]
```

As I said, the validation to make is that one of the child objects for every Post object must be informed: either an Image or a VideoLink or both